# Prove that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $3\nmid\phi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

My thoughts are to choose any number of the form $2^k$, $5^k$ or any number combined of both of these two like $10,50,100$ and so on. The reasoning follows from the closed form of $\phi(n)$. Sorry for the duplication to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512706/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-integers-n-so-that-3-does-not-divide-phi) but I feel this proof is much easier and natural to come up with. Is that right?

Comment: by $\phi(n)$ I meant Euler phi function.

Comment: Why not add your solution as an answer to the linked question?

Comment: @lhf I want to check first.

Comment: @lhf just did so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solutions are correct.  Indeed $$\varphi(2^k)=2^{k-1}\quad \&\quad \varphi(5^k)=5^{k-1}\times 4$$

It is easy to generate more examples, such as $$\varphi(11^k)=11^{k-1}\times 10\quad \text {or}\quad \varphi(17^k)=17^{k-1}\times 16$$

Comment: This is another form of numbers you mean. But numbers I had given are sufficient to prove, are not they?

Comment: Yes!  My apologies, I read too quickly.  I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your effort,,

Comment: just added a reference to your answer to the duplicate question @lulu

Comment: Thank you, though there was no need.  You came up with the solution without my help, I just confirmed it.

Comment: Worth noting:  I agree with you that your solution improves on the older one, in that you actually exhibit some infinite families of examples.  Even the constructive proofs of the infinitude of primes in this or that arithmetic progression don't really provide a convenient list of examples.

Comment: Yeah, @lulu, I felt it a little bit complicated with it is much easier and elegant to consider this two forms.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_m^{k_m}$.  Recall that you have $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1} (p-1)$, and $\phi$ is a multiplicative function -- that is,

$$ \phi(p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_m^{k_m}) = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{k_i-1} (p_i-1) $$

For the right hand side to be divisible by 3, it must have a factor that's divisible by 3.  For a factor of 3 to come from $p_i^{k_i-1}$ we must have $p_i = 3$ and $k_i \ge 2$ - that is, $n$ is divisible by $3^2$.  For a factor of 3 to come from $p_i - 1$, $p_i$ must be one more than a multiple of 3.

So $\phi(n)$ is not divisible by 3 if, and only if, it has no prime factors of form $3j + 1$ and at most one prime factor of $3$.  It's clear that there are infinitely many such numbers, for example those families given by lulu.  The sequence is at https://oeis.org/A088232.